# Is there a way to seperate ractive scripts in different html or js files?

Tags: ractivejs

I have many scripts inside of my index.html file that holds all my Ractive scripts. I am wondering if there was some way to organize this all and have these scripts in different html or js files.

Here's what I mean:

```
//index.html
<script type="text/html" id="template-1">
...content...
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="template-2">
...content...
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="template-3">
...content...
</script>
```

Here's what I am trying to accomplish

```
//template1.html or js
<script type="text/html" id="template-1">
...content...
</script>

//template2.html or js
<script type="text/html" id="template-2">
...content...
</script>

//template3.html or js
<script type="text/html" id="template-3">
...content...
</script>
```

I have tried doing it this way, and I get errors since my ractive objects are on my index.html, and there's no way to include other html files. I'm sure other people have had this problem before, is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked into using Ractive components?

Comment: Yes, but that would not allow to have separate logic for each.

Answer (score 1):

You should use per-file [components](https://github.com/ractivejs/component-spec/blob/master/authors.md). This allows you to package one component into one file, script, styles and markup while still keeping the separation between them. In order to use components, you need to use loaders which are [available in just about every module management/bundling system out there](https://github.com/ractivejs/component-spec#available-loaders).

Answer (score 1):

You could use php or some other server side script

```
<?php

include_once('a.html');

include_once('b.html');

include_once('c.html');

?>
```

Comment: This is also what I'm doing and combined with Page.js you can load the component you need.